# Can't install Ubuntu!

Tags: upgrade, flash, system-installation, unetbootin

Used UnetBootin to create it on the flash drive. Tells me to reboot, after rebooting, I press **DEL** key to enter the BIOS. I set the boot priority to my USB. I press <kbd>F10</kbd> and it saves it and reboots. After that Windows boots like normal.

I have also tried LinuxLive USB Creator but it still failed.

Maybe a Ubuntu Computer can help me? If it can help, please tell me as I have access to a local Cafe that has Ubuntu installed on their PC.

Comment: Unetbootin is really unreliable, try pendrivelinux.con as suggested.

Comment: Do you nessacarily have to use a USB. IMO creating a boot disk(CD or DVD) is much better, and it works great. Plus you have something to fall back to in case you corrupt your OS or GRUB.

Answer (score 1):

I personally haven't used UnetBootin, I use http://www.pendrivelinux.com/ to make bootable live USBs and it works well for me. You can use YUMI or UUI with your .iso file and try that.

Also try to go in to Boot Options instead of BIOS setup to find your USB manually.

Comment: Tried it already. Didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

First try *without* relying on *boot order*. Some (older) BIOS only expect to find a *floppy drive* or *hard drive* as a boot source. Interrupt the boot sequence and *force* "choose" (often **F9**) for the boot device.

---

### **The guaranteed fallback method is:** *Ask a friend.*

Find someone with a recent version of **Ubuntu** on their PC.

*Ask them to create a USB boot-disk for you.*

Comment: The only thing about F9 is it send me to BBS POPUP and DEL sends me to Setup and F12 to BIOS Post Flash unlike other PC's that I have which only show DEL for Setup and F12 to BBS POPUP.

Comment: What **brand/model** (and BIOS) of PC are you trying to install Ubuntu on to?

Comment: The PC is actually custom built. My current OS is Windows 7. BIOS is American Megatrends Inc. 080015 [4/15/2008]

Comment: Try **F8** or **F11**. See: https://www.ami.com/support/doc/AMIBIOS8_Keystrokes_PUB.pdf **OR** read: http://en.kioskea.net/faq/6609-how-to-boot-from-a-usb-device

Answer (score 0):

unetbootin did not work properly for me also, so I use the default " startup disk creator" this works fine on ubuntu

If you are on windows try this:"universalusbinstaller" this one also works.

Boot for pendrive(different for every bios), then start installation and it is as simple as that.

Comment: you can boot from pendrive by increasing the priority for your pendrive in boot order(in the bios), then "save and exit".

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be some confusion about your post. When you say, it tells you to reboot, do you mean after installation?

Using any kind of pen drive, after setting it up to be bootable and with the ubuntu on it, what you are doing is turning it on and hoping it will go directly to the pen drive, and you would see a purple screen and then have an option to install or try ubuntu.

It might be helpful if you explained more, I have a feeling there is more to this story.

Are you not able to:

successfully make the startup pen drive
successfully boot into the pen drive, or
other?

Comment: This might be long. UNetBootin tells me to reboot after it's done placing the contents on my flash drive. After I restart my PC. I press the **DEL** key to enter the BIOS. I go to the Boot Menu and change the 1st Boot Priority to the Removable Media [Sometimes it shows up as USB:2.0] After that I press F10 to save the changes and it restarts my PC. After that it goes to the American Megatrends Boot Screen and to my Hardware Monitor and then no purple screen comes up, instead the Windows boot screen appears with the starting Windows caption.

Comment: Ok I can understand now. Yeah the system obviously isn't recognizing your usb device and so is going directly into the windows. Now one note is, cd-roms usually are more reliable for installation than usb, I don't know if you could get the image burned or not (or have a cd-rom drive). But otherwise, see below, I don't have windows anymore and can't comment about it. Good luck!

Comment: That's the problem. My PC has a CD/DVD Drive that can't detect a CD and USB Ports are getting common now so some PC manufacturers don't include a CD/DVD Drive any more.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows try ultraiso. Open the iso image in ultraiso. `Click Tools->Write` disk image. Select usb drive name. Go. After completion try booting from usb drive.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help, probably the installed bootloader doesn't recognize the filesystem of your pendrive.

[How to fix syslinux error creating a bootable USB stick in Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142728/how-to-fix-syslinux-error-creating-a-bootable-usb-stick-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which image you used to install but for other finding this post: The minimal **netboot** install image (mini.iso) is not able to boot in EFI mode (at least on some bioses). I used the startup disk creator when testing.

It boots fine in legacy mode (and worse - my bios automatically retries in legacy mode..)

Protip: **Always** check if you're in efi mode (`ls /sys/firmware | grep efi`) before wasting time installing

This post has a workaround: https://www.onetransistor.eu/2015/12/install-ubuntu-minimal-cd-uefi-enabled.html?showComment=1580553249108#c2253167695859258494

Not sure where to find a non-netboot minimal install image?