# Ubuntu Error 15:(http://grub4dos.chenall.net/e/15) File not found

Tags: boot, 18.10, usb-installation, grub4dos

Recently I just downloaded Ubuntu-18.10-desktop-amd64 and make a bootable USB by universal usb installer. But when I boot this on my laptop it's showing following errors :

```
Booting 'Boot ubuntu-18.10-desktop-amd64'

(hd0,0)
Filesystem type is iso9660_Joliet, using whole disk [Linux-bzImage, setup=0x4200, size=0x821b58]
initrd /casper/ILUG

Error 15:(http://grub4dos.chenall.net/e/15) File not found

Press any key to continue...
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

### For CDFS, make sure menu.lst case references are UPPERCASE

I got this error when attempting to boot from a USB drive that had been set bootable, made with the [Universal USB Installer](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/). During boot, I got the Error 15 message.

I had downloaded the [Ubuntu ISO image](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop) (18.04.3 LTS), and the file name was in lowercase (`ubuntu-18.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso`).

I used the [Universal USB Installer](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) tool to burn the image (also see [caveat](https://askubuntu.com/a/1195510/329795)).

When I booted, I got the Error 15 message. With [some research](http://reboot.pro/topic/12890-error-15file-not-found/), it seems that the CDFS file system is case sensitive.

To remedy, I inserted the USB drive into my Windows PC, and navigated to the `\boot\grub\menu.lst` file, and edited it, changing all instances of:

```
UBUNTU-18.04.3-DESKTOP-AMD64      ➜  UBUNTU-18.04.3-DESKTOP-AMD64
UBUNTU-18.04.3-DESKTOP-AMD64.ISO  ➜  UBUNTU-18.04.3-DESKTOP-AMD64.ISO
```

I also updated the ISO image filename in the root directory on the USB drive to be uppercase:

```
\UBUNTU-18.04.3-DESKTOP-AMD64.ISO
```

After these changes were made, I rebooted via USB, and it worked.

---

My final `menu.lst` looked like this:

```
# This Menu created with Universal USB Installer https://www.pendrivelinux.com
default 0
timeout 30
color NORMAL HIGHLIGHT HELPTEXT HEADING
foreground=FFFFFF
background=000000

title Boot UBUNTU-18.04.3-DESKTOP-AMD64
set ISO=/UBUNTU-18.04.3-DESKTOP-AMD64.ISO
set CASPER=/casper-rw
find --set-root %ISO%
map %ISO% (0xff)
#CLUG
map --hook
root (0xff)
kernel /casper/vmlinuz file=/preseed/ubuntu.seed noprompt boot=casper iso-scan/filename=%ISO% quiet --
initrd /casper/initrd

title Boot UBUNTU-18.04.3-DESKTOP-AMD64 acpi=off
set ISO=/UBUNTU-18.04.3-DESKTOP-AMD64.ISO
set CASPER=/casper-rw
find --set-root %ISO%
map %ISO% (0xff)
#CLUG
map --hook
root (0xff)
kernel /casper/vmlinuz file=/preseed/ubuntu.seed noprompt boot=casper iso-scan/filename=%ISO% quiet acpi=off --
initrd /casper/initrd
```